# How do you solve a general linear Diophantine equation in polynomial time?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations, discrete-optimization

If you google this one, you're going to get sickened by all the plaigiarization in the world going on.  Everyone is stuck on the obvious case of $n = 2$. I want for $n$ variables (general linear).

So given an equation of the form

$$
D = Ax + By + \dots + Cz \tag{1}
$$

in finitely many variables $n$, where $A, B, C, \dots, D \in \Bbb{Z}$ or in particular $\Bbb{N}$, how does one write down the general, parameterized solution?

Next question, given the general solution can we minimize $x + y + \dots + z$ over the set of solutions, all in polynomial time?

That is, can we do all of the above given $(1)$ in polynomial time and space complexity?

---

All solutions lay in $\Bbb{N}^n$, and in fact there are quite small bounds attached to each variable, such as $x \in \{0, 2\}$ for smallish instances of my input problem.  However combined this can naively be approximately $2^n$ or more points to try.  That is not polynomial time.

Comment: I don't understand why you were voted down. this question is interesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to define my notations a bit more clearly and try to make myself clearer. I consider the equation $B=\sum_{i=1}^n{A_ix_i}$, where the $x_i$ (and only them) are unknowns in $\mathbb{Z}^n$.

I am denoting, for any vector $z \in \mathbb{Z}^n$, $\|z\|_1=\sum_{k=1}^n{|z_k|}$ and $\|z\|_0=|\{k,\,z_k \neq 0\}$, and $d(z)$ the gcd of the entries of $z$.

$G_n$ is the group of invertible $n \times n$ matrices with integer entries, such that their reciprocals have also integer entries.

A transvection is a $n \times n$ matrix $M$ with entries in $\mathbb{Z}$, all diagonal entries equal to $1$, and exactly one other nonzero entry. It is always in $G_n$.

The first part is to check that for all $M \in G_n$, $z \in \mathbb{Z}^n$, $d(Mz)=d(z)$. This is because $d(z)$ “clearly” divides $d(Mz)$, and $z=M^{-1}(Mz)$ so the inverse divisibility also holds.

The key lemma is as follows: let $a \in \mathbb{Z}^n$. If $\|a\|_0 \geq 2$, then there exists a transvection $M \in G_n$ such that $\|Ma\|_1 < \|a\|_1$.

Proof: there exists indices $i \neq j$ and an integer $k$ such that $0 < a_i-ka_j < |a_i|$. So take for $M$ the only transvection such that $M_{i,j}=-k$.

So we can construct (each of the constructions in “linear” time) vectors $A^0=A=(A_1, \ldots, A_n), A^1, \ldots, A^p$ and transvections $M_1, \ldots, M_p$, such that $M_iA^{i-1}=A^i$, and $\|A^i\|_1$ decreases, and $\|A^p\|=1$.

Thus, $p \leq \|A\|_1/d(A)$ (ie the procedure must stop).

Since $d(A^p)=d(A)$ and $\|A^p\|=1$, it can be found (in linear time) a matrix $N \in G_n$ such that $NA^p=(d(A),0,0,\ldots,0)$.

Note that for any matrix $M$ and any transvection $P$ (of which one already knows the location of the nondiagonal nonzero entry), $MP$ can be computed by a single column operation in $M$, ie by in linear time.

So $M=NM_p\ldots M_1$ can be computed in $O(np)=O(n\|A\|_1/d(A))$ time such that $(d(A),0,\ldots,0)=MA$.

As a consequence, let $z \in \mathbb{Z}^n$, write $z=\sum_{i=1}^n{\alpha_iL_i(M)}$, where $L_i(M)$ is the $i$-th line of $M$.

Then since $A \cdot L_i(M)=L_i(MA)=0$ if $i \geq 2$ and $d(A)$ if $i=1$, so $\sum_{i=1}^n{z_iA_i}=\alpha_1d(A)$.

Thus $\{z,\,B=\sum_{i=1}^n{A_iz_i}\}$ is freely generated by $B/d(A)L_1(M)$ (if $d(A)$ does not divide $B$ the set is instead empty) and all $L_k(M)$, $k \geq 2$.

I am not sure how much it helps you to find solutions in non-negative integers though.

Comment: What is $\| \cdot \|_{L^k}$?

Comment: Also, please explain maybe with an example, alternatively define more your symbols if you have time.  Thank you!  Or a reference would work.

Comment: It should if there are finite solutions in positive integers. Then those become the first solutions otherwise, you'd have to search for them. or just use ILP simplex algorithm. which is much worse.